# Devolver un JSON desde servidor ASP.NET a una variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net

Estoy intentando devolver una cadena string que contiene un JSON desde el servidor a una variable en Javascript.
En el servidor tengo un programa en ASPX con una funcion llamada Prueba() que devuelve este JSON

```
Public string Prueba()
  {
    return "[ { \"ARGUMENTO\": \"2 \", \"DESCRIPCION\": \"Dos\" }, { \"ARGUMENTO\": \"1 \", \"DESCRIPCION\": \"Uno\" } ]";       
  }
```

En Javascript tengo lo siguiente:

```
var arr = JSON.parse('<%=Prueba()%>');
var JObject = JSON.parse(arr);
alert(JObject[0].ARGUMENTO);
```

Tendria que mostrarme un alert con el mensaje "2" pero no me muestra nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás intentando parsear dos veces el JSON. La función `JSON.parse()` se utiliza para parsear una cadena JSON y convertirla en un objeto JavaScript. En tu caso, estás tratando de parsear la cadena JSON dos veces: una vez al recibir la cadena desde el servidor y otra vez después de asignarla a la variable `arr`.

Deberías de hacer:

```
var arr = <%=Prueba()%>;
alert(arr[0].ARGUMENTO);
```

`arr` ya es un objeto JavaScript porque la función `Prueba()` devuelve una cadena JSON que es interpretada como un objeto JavaScript al asignarse a la variable `arr`. Por lo tanto, no necesitas llamar a `JSON.parse()` nuevamente.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: funciona perfectamente gracias !